# Using volley to communicate with web server

Tags: php, android, json, android-volley

i am trying to practice using volley to communicate with my web server i setup a simple task to retrieve a pre set string just to test it all works fine

however i get the error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in json_test.php
```

Here is the part of the android code that  is involved

```
    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                urli, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                jsonArrayTextView.setText(response.toString());

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                jsonArrayTextView.setText("Error: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        });

// Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_json_arry);
```

Here is the php code

```
    <?php


$output_string = "Hello World"

echo json_encode($output_string);
?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot a semicolon. So `$output_string = "Hello World";`